# Automate graph generation based on variable time

Tags: vba, excel

I need help creating an Excel macro.

I want to take the Excel file [here](http://pastebin.com/9VLDHPAX) and create a graph of each of the servers with time being the x axis and memory utilizaiton % being the y axis. The problem is, the number of data points for each server can be variable (sometimes the first server has x number of data points, other times it has x+2).

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Sure. If I'm understanding correctly, you need to create a chart where your data can grow in size. In that case you need to use a "dynamic named range" that expands as new data is added. The chart that you will end up creating is called a "dynamic chart". The dynamic range is set up using the OFFSET function which allows it to expand.

I think these videos will help you:

Excel 2010 / 2007: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M9hhUVljTx4
Excel other: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7le-m8YRP6M